# iOS9 beta - SKEffectNode/CIFilter bug?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, beta, ios9, skeffectnode

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I went wrong somewhere:

I have a class A which is a subclass of SKScene and a Class B which is a Subclass of SKEffectnode. I then add the class B as a child of class A.
The class B has a blurfilter property:

```
private let blurFilter : CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
private func createBlurView() {  
    blurFilter.setDefaults()  
    blurFilter.setValue(10, forKey: "inputRadius")  
    self.filter = blurFilter  
    self.shouldEnableEffects = false  
}
```

When the user touches a certain node the effects gets enabled:

```
self.shouldEnableEffects = true
```

The devices either renders the effect and then the app terminates or the effect doesnt get rendered and the app terminates. XCode throws the following error:

**/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IOAcceleratorFamily/IOAcceleratorFamily-201.1/Framework/IOAccelResourceRef.c:45: failed assertion `Resource freed while busy'**

I created the same scene in XCode 6.4 on iOS 8.4 and had no error, everything worked.

Is there something wrong with my code? Otherwise I am going to report this as a bug.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the issue to Apple. It was a bug and they fixed it with iOS9 beta 5.